# What does Roberto mean when he says “Dish duty is really trimming down the wardrobe”?

Tags: marvel, new-mutants

> ROBERTO: Dish duty is really trimming down the wardrobe.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

You missed the next lines.

> ROBERTO: Dish duty is really trimming down the wardrobe.
>
> **RAHNE: Every time your shirt gets dirty… you just throw it away?**
>
> **ROBERTO: Here. It’s all yours.**

He means that when he does the dishes and gets his clothes dirty as a result, his wardrobe is diminished (['*trimmed down*'](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/trimmed+down#:%7E:text=trim%20%2D%20cut%20down%20on%3B%20make,his%20trip%20due%20to%20illness%22)) because he won't wear clothes that have been covered in food waste and dirty dishwater, ever if there's cleaning available.